# Regex Extracting Data from outlook message

Tags: extract

I am trying to extract some information from outlook email messages and write the output to a text file. I a doing it in a macro by getting the emails in a specific folder and then parse each message for specific strings. Sample input string below

```
[optional strings here]
Name: John Doe
[optional strings here]
Email: u@me.com
[optional strings here]
Tel: 555-555-5555
```

I tried using a regex to extract the information however I am not able to come up with the proper regex that will extract what I need and ignore the rest

Here is what I have so far:

```
(^.*\b(Name|E-mail|Primary-Phone)\b.*$)
```

Answer (score 0):

With some offline help I got the regex that does what I need:

```
\n?Name:\t*?([^\t]*?)\t*?\r.*?E-mail:\t*?([^\t]*?)\t*?\r.*?phone:\t*?(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}).*?
```

Thanks
Timur